# How can i fix npm install errors

Tags: reactjs

I have clone the code but when I want to do npm install, I get below error. What does this error mean.

My project was running before i pulled the code but then I am getting this error.

My npm version - 7.21.0
Node - v14.17.4

```
npm ERR! While resolving: netflex@0.0.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from hst-react-components-lib@1.0.48
    npm ERR! node_modules/***hst
    npm ERR!   hst-react-components-lib@"^1.0.47" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: react 16.13 is kind of a while ago now, 17 came out October 2020... are you still using 16?

Comment: Yes, I need to fix the issue in this version only.

Comment: Try updating the React version in `package.json`

Comment: Try running `npm cache clean --force`  from your root folder. Then run npm install. I hope you got the package.lock.json when you cloned the project and not a new one generated.

Comment: @SanishJoseph didn't help. Tried that